# Enums as strings or string constants

Tags: c#, enums

I came across [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/stefansedich/archive/2008/03/12/enum-with-string-values-in-c.aspx) blog post and I was just curious. I usually always use `constants` for my shared strings across my application.

I was wondering what you think the pros/cons of doing it the former way are though?

Comment: Are your string constants related to one another through some series or set? If not, don't use an enum.

Comment: They can imply that relation. Enums of ints don't need to be sequentially related either.

Comment: if your using .net 4, use the Description that already exists, don't reinvent the wheel :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would stick with string constants since they are straightforward and don't require any reflection to get the values.

Answer (score 2):

The method there uses reflection to extract the string value. If you are doing something performance critical avoid this at all cost... constants are the way to go if you want speed.

More than that by using the method there you seriously hurt the compiler optimizer because each 'constant' now become a 'method call'.

Comment: it may be unique, but what you must leverage when you are developing are the 'pro' and 'contra'. Uniqueness is neither.

Answer (score 2):

That largely depends on what kinds of string you're storing.

If it's something like text shown to users, then you shouldn't be using constants in the first place. Read-only fields are better and resources better yet.

The main disadvantage I can see in the proposed solution is that it's going to be very unintuitive: when I see usage of string constant or field, I immediately know what's going on. If I see `SomeEnum.SameValue.GetStringValue()`, I would assume it does pretty much what `ToString()` would do, not some funny business.

Also, using reflection like that is going to be much slower, but that might not matter to you.